# Excel VBA Search button click

Tags: html, excel, vba

Im having issues getting my search button to click after I pass in search values from my excel. Right now, the value successfully gets passed in, but the macro then breaks when search button needs to be clicked.

Code below:

```
ie.document.getElementById("searchbar").Value = var
'Here we are clicking on search Button
Set form = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("submitbtn")
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
Set button = form(0).submit
form(0).submit
```

Html:

```
   <input value="Submit" type="submit" id="submitbtn">
```

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You'll also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think you want `getElementByID("submitbtn")` instead.

Comment: FWIW your naming is terribly misleading. a "form" isn't a "button", and I doubt `.submit` returns an object (or does it?) - if it doesn't, then that `Set button` instruction is wrong.